# Can App-V be used to prevent software piracy?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, app-v

I would like to deploy an expensive proprietary software to users in a Remote Desktop environment (users are only using RDP to connect to our servers). I would like to allow them to run and use the full potential on the software, but only on our server. They should not have the ability to copy the program files.

One solution to achieve this is App Locker, but is it also possible with App-V?

Comment: Making users jump through hoops to use expensive software makes me look for less draconian alternatives. I'm sure many others are the same. A lot of times when companies try to "protect" their software, all they're doing is protecting it from being purchased.

Comment: Our users are happy with RDP, they have been for a long time and they will be. Using APP-V does not mean "jumping through hoops" but can be a great solution to centrally manage software. If it also protects software from being stolen, it is a great side effect. Please be consructive next time.

Comment: Mark was giving an opinion based on his experience; it's an experience shared by a number of other admins when encountering a question of "we want to use our **expensive proprietary** software and prevent it from being copied" type questions. Coupling it with a remark like "Please be constructive next time" doesn't help the case. He's pointing out that making users do anything to introduce friction to the process of using the software is going to lessen the experience and give more reason for admins/users to look elsewhere, which I've found to be true as well. Your comment over-defensive.

Comment: @Heinrich my problem isn't with RDS or App-V as a mode of delivery to end users. What I do have a problem with is a vendor trying to deliver an application to *my* server through App-V. This would allow them to publish whatever code/update they want without my review. This is **not** something that I, or many other admins that I know, would allow in their enviroment. I'm fine using RDS or App-V, but not when it means I lose control of the content on my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. App-V may provide the application files in an obfuscated manor, but will not prevent someone who knows what they're doing from copying those files. I run App-V extensively in our environment and would have little difficulty extracting all the original files from an App-V source.

That said, MS could extend App-V, perhaps pairing it with ADRMS, to create a solution like you are suggesting. The functionality is not currently there however.